# OTP verification failed pyotp

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on a django rest framework project, everything is working file but i encounter 1 problem

```
class OTP:
    @staticmethod
    def generate_otp():
        base32secret3232 = pyotp.random_base32()
        otp = pyotp.TOTP(base32secret3232, interval=300, digits=6, )
        time_otp = otp.now()
        return time_otp, base32secret3232

    @staticmethod
    def verify_otp(user, otp):
        return pyotp.TOTP(user.get("otp_secret"), interval=300, digits=6).verify(otp)
```

Here OTP for user is generated successfully and i saved otp and secret in that user record and i send the user a email containing that otp for account verification. When user send the otp then for the first time it shows invalid OTP, then on subsequent changes it verify the user.I want to solve that issue

First I check that whether I am entering the correct otp or not and otp,secret saved in database correctly or not. And these are working correctly.
I want this issue to be resolved.